# Complex Histogram in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, histogram, data-analysis

I am new to R, but I need to create a histogram. I cannot, however simply use ggplot_histogram.

I have a column of numbers: 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10

The histogram I want to make should only have five bins, one wide. The result I want should have the x axis be frequency of repetitions and the y axis be the number of times a number repeated the x-axis number of times.

From the list given above, I want that there were two values that repeated once, three values that repeated twice, two values that repeated thrice, etc. Is there a function for this in R or does it involve a convoluted way of manipulating the columns and making multiple histograms? I would do it manually but I have 50,000+ rows.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by your x axis, could you clarify and perhaps even provide an illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out there is two values repeated once, three values that repeated 2x, two values repeated 3x and so on, call `table` twice:

```
> table(table(data))

1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 2 1 1
```

You can wrap this in `barplot` to get the chart you described:

```
> barplot(table(table(data)))
```

[image: table table bar]